# Vim Regex match occurence X if occurence Y does not exist between X and Z

Tags: regex, vim

Assume I have an occurence

```
GET.CUSTOMER:
```

and an occurence

```
GET.ACCOUNT:
```

How should the Regex expression be formulated if I want the above occurence to be matched only and only if there is no occurence of word

```
RETURN
```

Between

```
 GET.CUSTOMER:
        BLOCK OF CODE
```

and

```
 GET.ACCOUNT:
        ANOTHER BLOCK OF CODE
```

For this to be generic, assume that an anchored colon is only allowed in function name, so there can be no colons "stuck" to a word other than the function's name. I.e

```
RANDOM.FUNCTION:
```

Is allowed, but

```
RANDOM.LINE.OF.CODE : MORE.CODE
```

Is not allowed, except in a string within quotes and apostrophes.

This matching will be used in a Vim syntax file, and not in actual code.

@EDIT
The question: Is the above even possible? Which regex expressions should I look into that might help me solve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Also, please clarify: You want `GET.CUSTOMER:` highlighted, but only if there's no `RETURN` between it and `GET.ACCOUNT:`?!

Comment: I'm very sorry, I got a little carried away and forgot to include the actual question, which is: Is the above even possible?

The answer to your second comment is yes. I want GET.CUSTOMER: to be highlighted only if there's not RETURN between it and GET.ACCOUNT:

I tried using forward lookup, but I've only started using Regex yesterday to write my own   syntax highlighter - hence the question

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you're not looking for a single regex. You're looking for syntax options to parse your file. Look into `:help usr_44.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will match `GET.CUSTOMER:`, if it is followed by `GET.ACCOUNT:`, but there's no `RETURN` in between the two. You might need to tweak this a bit; I've left our keyword boundary assertions and other fluff here. Also, as this is a multi-line match, it might be slow or break down if there are too many lines in between.

```
syntax match getCustomerBlockWithoutReturn
\   "\%#=1\%(GET\.CUSTOMER:\_.\{-}\%(RETURN\|GET\.ACCOUNT:\)\)\@>\%(GET\.ACCOUNT:\)\@<="
\   contains=getCustomer
syntax match getCustomer "GET\.CUSTOMER:" contained
hi link getCustomer Statement
```

The first `getCustomerBlockWithoutReturn` matches the whole block. `getCustomer` is contained in the former (the `contained` prevents matching outside of it) and performs the highlighting via the `:highlight` group. This is because you only want to highlight the word that starts the block, not the whole block itself.

The main challenge with this regular expression is that usually, *backtracking* tries really hard to find a match, and it would skip over `GET.ACCOUNT:` ... `GET.CUSTOMER:` parts just to find a `RETURN` and make the match, even if that spans multiple actual blocks.

By using the (obscure) *whole pattern* multi ([`:help /\@>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3E)), we're preventing backtracking and match a minimal (via `\{-}`) area (including newlines by using `\_.` instead of `.`) from `GET.CUSTOMER:` to either `RETURN` or `GET.ACCOUNT:`. A *positive lookbehind* (via [`/\@<=`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D)) then asserts that this end actually is `GET.ACCOUNT:`, i.e. that we have a block without a `RETURN` in it. (Note: At least in my Vim version 8.1.536, I had to force use of the older regexp engine via `\%#=1`; I [have reported](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3651) that bug to the Vim developers.)